# UIInterfaceOrientation bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iPhone app I need to detect the current orientation and I have to determine if I'm in portrait or landscape. I use this code:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
     NSLog(@"portrait");
     ...
} else {
     NSLog(@"landscape");
     ...
}
```

Everything is ok when my iPhone is in my hand.
But when i put it on the table and i run the application, the content is displayed on the screen in **portrait mode** and my code goes to else and **NSLog prints landscape**.

Is my test incomplete ? How to prevent this case ?

**EDIT** : the test is performed in my controller viewDidLoad method and my application handle rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIDevice.orientation` is of type `UIDeviceOrientation`, which is a superset of `UIInterfaceOrientation`. You are probably getting the value `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`.

This underscores that yes, your test is incomplete. You should write something like this:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
     NSLog(@"portrait");
     ...
} else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
     NSLog(@"landscape");
     ...
} else {
     NSLog(@"WTF? %d", orientation);
     assert(false);
}
```

Then, you'll know if you if you've missed something.

Comment: what do you mean, i'm not sure to understand how it can help for my problem ?

Comment: @lefakir: The device is telling you that it is flat on its back. Read @par's answer.

Answer (score 2):

UIDevice.orientation can return that the device is flat or upside down (not inverted portrait, upside-down as in laying on its face).  Instead call UIViewController.interfaceOrientation on your root view controller.

Comment: your response is also right but Marcelo Cantos answered first even if it wasn'nt really well explained (from my point of view) in the first version

Comment: I'm good, but really for interface orientation you should not use [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation.  Rather in your main UIViewController query the interfaceOrientation property (see UIViewController.h).  That method always returns either portrait or landscape and never the face up/down constants so it is probably more likely what you are really interested in knowing (i.e. whether you're in portrait or landscape).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation)`

It will tell you if its a valid orientation (valid being either landscape or portrait, not FaceUp/FaceDown/UnKnown). Then you can treat it as if its portrait if its unknown.

This is how I do it:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(interfaceOrientation) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
    // handle landscape
} else {
    // handle portrait
}
```